# how to popup window for editing row with ng-grid and angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I've just started to read about angular-js. It seems really cool to learn. I've also looked through http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/. ng-grid seems nice and easy to use, however I am not sure how to popup a modal window when the edit button is clicked on for a given row? And then when the "Save" button is clicked, the content is then updated/refreshed on the grid with the row highlighted.

Something like http://www.jtable.org/. I don't want to fix jtable and angular js together.

Anyone please help?

Thanks & regards
Tin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding column template

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/2GZ7L/10/)

i have hide and show a div, by giving it an id you can give it pop up look of Jquery

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    enablePaging: true,
    columnDefs: [{field: 'id', displayName: 'ID', enableCellEdit: false,  colFilterText: ''},
                 {field:'name', displayName:'Name', enableCellEdit: true, colFilterText: '' },
                 {field:'edit', displayName:'Edit', enableCellEdit: true, cellTemplate: editContactCellTemplate, colFilterText: ''}]
```

Comment: Thank you Vinod. Almost there, I thought we could do it with ng-modal or something equivalent instead of jquery.

Comment: I get a js-Error which says no ui found, tested on ie11 and chrome 36.